# Ag-grid Parent Child communication

Tags: ag-grid

I have created a custom header component ( a child component within the component containing ag-grid). The header component will add some buttons along with the header name. While clicking on the buttons, the column field has to change accordingly. The code to change column definition is in parent component. I could achieve this functionality with normal buttons within the parent component. But while using header component, I don't know how to pass which button has been clicked from child (header) to parent (ag-grid). If I use event bus, (Subject and Observer) I couldn't specify the header component in grid options (shows type error). Event emitter is not working.

Comment: you can use this npm package [ngx-pub-sub](https://npmjs.com/package/@pscoped/ngx-pub-sub), pass all the details with parameters. on the button click, publish the data: `service.publishEvent('headerButton1Click', { your: data })`

Comment: Curious how you solved this. I have a similar problem. I have a button in a custom column header renderer which when clicked I would like to delete that column. Obviously the parent of the grid has the master set of data and colDefs from which the column needs to be deleted. In normal angular I would just use an EventEmitter in the custom component, but as far as I know there is no way to get ag-grid to pass that event out from the header, through the ag-grid component to the parent.

Any advice here?